# AngularJS UI-Grid 3 Filter by Date

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

i try to filter a Grid by Date

```
$scope.filterDate = function () {
        $scope.state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
        if ($scope.state.columns[3].filters.length != 0) {
            $scope.state.columns[3].filters.length = 0;
        };
        // Try 1
        $scope.state.columns[3].filters.push({ condition: function(cellvalue) {
                return $scope.filter.startDate >= cellvalue;
            }
        });
        //Try 2
        $scope.state.columns[3].filters.push({ term: $scope.filter.endDate, condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN });
        $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, $scope.state);
    }
```

But the two tries do not really work. Somebody got an example or can help me ?

Comment: Do you mean the filter does not appear? Or that it does not filter as expected when activated? More detail on what doesn't work would be useful. Also, are the dates in the date JavaScript Date objects? For example, my sorting by dates of data received in Json format needs all of the date values to be transformed into JavaScript Dates in order to work. Maybe you've already done, but thought I'd check...

Comment: Hi, Try 1 did not execute the function, try2 filter something but not the date. Both fields (cellvalue and the endate) are javascript date fields. i did not transform something.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with saveState.restore as well when I was toggling column visible via code.

I resolved it using $timeout... maybe it will help you as well:

```
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, $scope.state);
            });
```